# Why TranslateService Angular does not add current language to localStorage?

Tags: angular

I use this approach to set current language:

```
this.translate.addLangs(['en', 'es']);
this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
this.translate.use(); // Get data from local Storage.
```

Object `environment` has data about languages, therefore it is not empty.

So, before it had worked and added language property in local storage with selected language. Now does not work.

Comment: We don't know what `TranslateService` and `environment` are ? It's not built-in features

Comment: I have edited question, check out please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not the most accurate question I have seen but i will try to answer with my code and hope it helps you out.
This is how I usually deal with this situation:

```
if (!(localStorage.getItem('selectedLangCode'))) {
            if (navigator.language === 'en' || navigator.language === 'en-US') {
                localStorage.setItem('selectedLangCode', '' + 'EN');
                this.translate.use('EN');
                moment.locale('EN');
            } else {
        this.translate.use(localStorage.getItem('selectedLangCode'));
        moment.locale(localStorage.getItem('selectedLangCode'));
    }
```